# BotBuilder Authentication Multitenant

Tags: azure, botframework

I want to create Microsoft BotBuilder [following this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant#bot-identity-information). But it seems SO complicated compared to v3.(BTW: starting a tutorial with 3 authentications that cover 75% of the article is not a good sign)

So I follow the EchoBot sample (I chose MultiTenant because my server is outside AND it seems the most covered):

```
const credentialsFactory = new BotBuilder.ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
    MicrosoftAppId: '***',
    MicrosoftAppPassword: '***',
    MicrosoftAppType: 'MultiTenant',
});

const botFrameworkAuthentication = BotBuilder.createBotFrameworkAuthenticationFromConfiguration(null, credentialsFactory);


const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context, error) => { /* for errors */ }
const adapter = new BotBuilder.CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication);
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;
```

**Questions:**

- How do I test everything is working ? `isValidAppId()` and `isAuthenticationDisabled()` are the only available method and seems OK.
- How do I get `MicrosoftAppPassword` ? According to the documentation I have to click manage, then create a `value/secret` pair. Should I use `value` ? or `secret` ? Why none is named `password` ? Anyway none works ...

**To test if it works, I follow the sample:**

- setup an HTTP POST Endpoint (with Node-RED)
- declare the endpoint in Azure Portal Bot Configuration
- go to webchat to test

I correctly receive the Messages then try to do some authentication/parisng (I assume) :

```
await adapter.process(msg.req, msg.res, (context) => {
    /* do some stuff  */
});
```

But it fails with a very explicit error :

```
Error: 1 validation issue(s)

  Issue #0: custom_error at [[root]]
  Response
```

I think, the errors is related to an authentication issue, since I don't understand what/how to set the password. I guess I have to go through this `CloudAdapter` in order to get a parsed  `context` and be able to send messages.

**EDIT 07/05/2022:**

I use the AppId from here :
[image]

I click "Manage" but where is the AppPassword ?
[image]

**EDIT 12/05/2022:**

Using cURL I manage to validate the appID and appPassword (the value (hidden by stars) of the secret).

BotBuilder is mixing the Communication Stack (HTTP / WebSocket) and the Logic stack (Turn Conversation). I think it's a bad habbit but I manage a workaround:

- I use a `BotFrameworkAdapter` instead of `CloudAdpater`
- I call `adapter.processActivity()` instead of `adapter.process()`

The adapter still want to end() the request and set deprecated values but it works in Node-RED. The `context` handle all the requirement to call `sendActivity()` anywhere multiple times.

Comment: CURL Authentication works, with AppID and the value of the Client Secret. SO the problem is located in adapter.process(req,res) that is doing some kind of websocket connection underhood my server didn't like

Answer (score -1):

To answer second question in your case, kindly go through the link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant

To answer the first question in your case, kindly check disabling and enabling the authentication to test the app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I read the documentation and try all deploy version but do not understand what to put in the password field of the API.

Comment: I'll guess/try the curl option. It didn't work it may be a good start

Answer (score -1):

As far as getting the password goes, when you create a new Multi Tenant Azure Bot resource, the app password goes into the Azure Key Vault created alongside it. The AppId and AppPassword are randomly generated by Azure. You can get them from the key vault in the Azure portal in the correct resource group.

If you want to create a resource manually using the CLI and define your own password, you can use this docs page for [deploying a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cnewgroup%2Ccsharp). Make sure you select the correct tabs. I have pre-selected C# and Multi Tenant in a new resource group for the above link.

Single Tenant is for limiting your bot's connections to Azure resources within the same tenant, and a User Assigned Managed Identity is if you want to make use of an Azure Managed Identity across the bot's resources instead of having a password for each resource.

You should be able to simply add the AppId and AppPassword to the echo bot sample and deploy it.

Comment: I update question with screenshot. I assume the password is the "value" generated when in the keyvault created when clicking on "manage" ?

Comment: If that's what the docs say, yes. Otherwise, you can always use the manual CLI method.